# how to target an element of our class with hive to change it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

good morning,
I don't know how to access an element of my boxHive without rebuilding it
I would like to be able to update some information without changing the existing one

Here is how I do it here, I use the constructor of my model class to add notes but it rebuilds all my class at the same time I would like it to rebuild only ListNote

```
class InformationPatient extends StatefulWidget {
  final Patients patients;
  final int index;

  const InformationPatient(this.patients, this.index, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InformationPatient> createState() => _InformationPatientState();
}

class _InformationPatientState extends State<InformationPatient> {
  late Box<Patients> boxPatient;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    boxPatient = Hive.box('Patient');
  }

  void _addNote(String newtitle, String newnote, String newconclusion) {
    final newNOTE = Patients(
      listOfNotes: [
        ListNote(title: newtitle, note: newnote, conclusion: newconclusion)
      ],
    );
    boxPatient.put(widget.index, newNOTE);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

**And here is my class model**

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

part 'listpatient.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Patients {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String? name;

  @HiveField(1)
  final String? firstname;

  @HiveField(3)
  final String? dateofbirth;

  @HiveField(4)
  final String? email;

  @HiveField(5)
  final String? phonenumber;

  @HiveField(6)
  final DateTime? date;

  @HiveField(7)
  final int? id;

  @HiveField(8)
  final List<ListNote>? listOfNotes;

  const Patients({
    this.name,
    this.firstname,
    this.dateofbirth,
    this.email,
    this.phonenumber,
    this.date,
    this.id,
    this.listOfNotes,
  });
}

@HiveType(typeId: 10)
class ListNote {
  @HiveField(1)
  final String? title;

  @HiveField(2)
  final String? note;

  @HiveField(3)
  final String? conclusion;

  ListNote({
    this.title,
    this.note,
    this.conclusion,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Hive` offers only Write and Read operations, as you can see from its [official documentation for flutter](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/read_write)

so in order to update an Object in your `boxPatient` Box you need to get it with this:

```
    Patients patients = boxPatient.get(widget.index);
```

then make your edits over it, then save it again on that same key:

```
    boxPatient.put(widget.index, patients);
```

you can say we just updated it with this process.